# Contar items repetidos en un listbox

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un listbox con una serie de elementos y quisiera saber el código para encontrar las veces que un elemento se repite, por ejemplo:

```
producto A
producto A
producto A
producto A
producto B
producto B
```

guardar en variables que la frecuencia de `A` es 4 y la frecuencia de `B` es 2.

Answer (score 2):

De los items del listbox puedes obtener una colección de strings con los diferentes elementos.

A partir de ahí puedes obtener los valores diferentes y el número de apariciones haciendo un GroupBy con LINQ:

```
    Dim items = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)
    Dim totales = items.GroupBy((Function(i) i)) _
        .Select(Function(g) new KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)(g.Key, g.Count()))
    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String,Integer) In totales
        Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}")
    Next
```